# Best free HTML help builder

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a program that provides me a functionality to build help documentation that can be viewed in a browser.
It should be lookin like a standard help, mean: topics, sub categories etc. Which can include
graphics, can format text etc.

I found a few nice looking, but they cost like houndreds of dollars.
Also found freeware, but that program wasn't what im looking for.

Any suggestions guys (girls)?

EDIT:
This is not a duplicate. I didnt precise, but i dont want to make documentation from source code.
Forget about source code. 
My documentation can be about frogs, butterflies or something else. I added tag c# because there is no tag "documentation". (and colorlire c# code would be useful).

I just need progrma like this:
http://www.softany.com/winchm/screenshots.htm

But i need something really good, with alot of features.

:S (I promise my english will be better asfet post 1000 questions^^)

Comment: "wasn't what I'm looking for" - what program did you find and why didn't you like it (exacly *what* are you looking for)? This info will help getting good answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate HTML / Help files from VS 2010 C# XML documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781784/generate-html-help-files-from-vs-2010-c-sharp-xml-documentation)

Comment: You can try [West Wind Html Help Builder](http://helpbuilder.west-wind.com). There's a shareware version that can be used without charge, but prints a message on the bottom of the help content that can be removed by registering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandcastle is great, but is complex and hard to work with.

[Sandcastle HelpFile Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) makes it a lot easier. You can style the generated HTML files or use one of the existing templates.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you mean building help files from XMLDoc comments in code files, [SandCastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com) will do this

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used [NDOC 3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndoc3/) in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget MAML for portability and standardization (plus it works well with Sandcastle).

[What is the recommended help file format to use in a modern Windows app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246041/what-is-the-recommended-help-file-format-to-use-in-a-modern-windows-app/8246744#8246744)